# Does not or Might not?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

This is the message:

> The user might not fall under the scope of this policy.

It denotes that a setting is not applied to the user because the user is not part of the policy. He's surely not part of the policy. In this case, which is more appropriate to use?

> 1. The user might not fall under the scope of this policy
> 2. The user does not fall under the scope of this policy

Comment: This basic sort of question is better asked on the sister site, ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

> "The user might not fall under the scope of this policy"

In this case, it is entirely possible that the user *does* fall under the scope of the policy; we simply don't know.

This is something you would use when describing business logic: we evaluate the policies the user *might* fall under, and for each policy we can state that the user *might* not fall under it. In which case, we would not apply the policy.

> "The user does not fall under the scope of this policy"

Now we know for sure that the policy does not apply to the user.

So, if you are sure the policy does not apply to this user, you use this form.